# Django: form_valid and model validation

Tags: python, django

I am creating a car reservation application in Django. Users can create a Reservation for a given Car. This happens at `/reservation/<car_id>/add`. This form does not contain the Car field because the id is given in the URL. Now I want to add a validation to the Reservation model so no reservations can overlap. I have the following code (minimal version):

```py
# models.py

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Reservation(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def clean(self):
        # Check if overlaps with other reservations in self.car.reservation_set

# views.py

class ReservationAdd(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'reservation/reservation_add.html'
    model = Reservation
    form_class = ReservationAddForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.car = Car.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['car_id'])
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

# forms.py

class ReservationAddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('start_time', 'end_time')
        model = Reservation
```

Now I get the following error at the `Reservation.clean` method:

```
reservation.models.Reservation.car.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Reservation has no car.
```

It seems to me that the `clean` method gets called before the `form_valid` method. So my design is not entirely correct I think. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. `form_valid` means "code to run once the form is confirmed as valid".

You need to make a couple of changes. Firstly, move your validation to the ReservationAddForm itself; and secondly, pass the Car instance into that form. So:

```
class ReservationAddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('start_time', 'end_time')
        model = Reservation

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.car = kwargs.pop('car')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        ... do something with self.car

class ReservationAdd(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'reservation/reservation_add.html'
    model = Reservation
    form_class = ReservationAddForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        self.car = Car.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['car_id'])
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['car'] = self.car
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.car = self.car
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I could add arguments to forms, but it does seem very simple to do. Thanks a lot for the clear answer!

Comment: But Daniel, what if there is an error after `form_valid`? How do we handle this error outside the form after it was validated already? Also, is not it incorrect to return an error from an already validated form?

Answer (score 1):

I think the better approach is

```
class ReservationAdd(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["car"] = Car.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['car_id'])
        return kwargs
```

and the model form override the `__init__` method

```
class ReservationAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.car = kwargs.pop("car")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

   def clean(self):
       # cleaned data
       cleaned_data = super().cleaned_data()
       # access the car instance using self.car
       # to do validation

       return cleaned_data
```